# Confidence Level and Interval probability

Tags: confidence-interval

I understand that the confidence level denotes how reliable is my test and the confidence level is not the probability associated with the confidence interval. This is well explained on Wikipedia:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Nevertheless, in Wikipedia it is also stated in the subsection "Misunderstandings" that: A 95% confidence level does not mean that for a given realized interval there is a 95% probability that the population parameter lies within the interval.

This is illogical to me. If the confidence interval denotes how reliable a test is, and if the test provides a given interval, I would deduce that the confidence interval is reliable with 95% of probability and hence the parameter is in the interval with 95% probability.

Why is my reasoning wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we can sample data from the population $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma = 4).$ You decide to find a 95% confidence interval for the unknown $\mu$ by looking at a random sample of size $n = 16.$ from this population.

Then $\bar X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu. \sigma = 4/\sqrt{16} = 1),$ so that
$$P(-1.96 \le \bar X - \mu \le 1.96) = P(\bar X - 1.96 \le \mu \le \bar X + 1.96) = 0.95.$$

Most statisticians are completely happy with that much, as long as $\bar X$ remains unobserved.

However, traditional frequentist statisticians object to saying that the statement $\mu \in (\bar X -1.96, \bar X +1.96)$ has probability $0.95,$ on the grounds that that this statement is now "either true or not true," but we don't know which and we can't assign a straightforward probability because $\bar X$ is now an observed value, not a random variable. (Much as in quantum mechanics, the 'probability' seems to 'collapse' as soon as $\bar X$ is observed. Never mind that
the 'true value' of $\mu$ never becomes available.)

Substitution of the word *confidence* for the word *probability* has become a standard way to meet that objection. Then each textbook author (and Wikipedia contributor) writes a version of the story that satisfies their own philosophical preference.

You join a long line of statistics students who have been puzzled by the statements of the various versions. If you are a 'peacemaker' you will latch onto one of the versions as your favorite and carefully parrot it word-for-word to future generations of
statisticians, tactfully suppressing (perhaps even eventually forgetting) your initial objections. You will avoid using the word *illogical,* however well you think it fits.

Bayesian statisticians avoid this thicket, beginning with the foundational viewpoint that $\mu$ is not an unknown fixed constant, but instead a random variable
with a prior distribution, but Bayesians have their own PR problems.